# Why is -2 & -1 equal to -2 in Go?

Tags: go, binary

Why does -2&-1 result in -2?
I assumed that 0010 & 0001 would result in 0000. Indeed it does when the numbers are positive.

```
fmt.Printf("%b, %b, %v\n", -2, -1, -2&-1)
// shows: -10, -1, -2
```

https://play.golang.org/p/2G3vDwxAy2J

Comment: -2 and -1 are negative, and are thus not 0010 and 0001

Comment: Yeah, there is the signing bit, but afaik that will just result in a negative number, no?

Comment: signing doesn't work how you're thinking, no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really a question about how numbers are represented in a computer, not about Go. You'd get the same result from other languages/environments like C or Python.

Let's assume 8 bits for simplicity. -2 is `11111110` in binary (using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is the standard way to represent negative integers in modern machines). -1 is `11111111` in binary. The `AND` of these is `11111110`, which is -2.

In reality Go integers are probably 32 or 64 bits, but this doesn't change the answer. Just add a bunch of 1s to the left of the representations mentioned above. The result is still `1111....1110` which is -2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got tricked by the fine prints in https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing :

`%b` in a format string stands for "base 2", not for "binary". What you get is a (symbolic) representation of the signed value in base 2 : `-10`, not a representation of the actual bits in memory.

One way to view the binary layout is to cast to the unsigned variant of the value :

```
    var i int32 = -2
    
    fmt.Printf("base2 = %b\n", i)
    fmt.Println("casting to unsigned :")
    fmt.Printf("base2 = %b\n", uint32(i))

// Output:
//   base2 = -10
//   casting to unsigned :
//   base2 = 11111111111111111111111111111110
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nfxS7Tv5HuL

note : the same applies to `%x` with a signed int : you get `-2` (a representation of the value in base 16), not `fffffffe`.